# How to guide a User To click on a View?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, androidx

I would like to guide a user of my app to click on a specific setting in my settings activity (not click automatically).
I've seen apps where the view gets the translucent ripple animation when the activity/fragment is opened to guide the user to Click on that item/view.
In My case,

```
AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Complete Sign Up")
            .setMessage("Please Enter Additional Details To complete Sign Up")
            .setPositiveButton("Take Me There") { dialog, whichButton ->
                   val settingsAlertIntent=Intent(this, SettingsActivity::class.java)
                   this.startActivity(settingsAlertIntent)
            }.setNegativeButton("I'll Do it later"){ dialog, whichButton ->
                   dialog.cancel()
            }
            .show()
```

After The Settings Intent is opened, I'd Like to show a ripple animation of some sort to guide the user to click on a view in the settings activity.

My idea was to get a background tint which was translucent and reset after a handler finishes,but seems to be a bad implementation.

Comment: You mean if the user clicks on the Information icon then the bubble can show with a description, right?

Comment: you can use tooltip show show the guide information and you can add animation to

Comment: @Amitpandey Same thing but with just the animation and should happen without the button being long pressed

Comment: @Ali Not Quite so, I'd like it just show a ripple automatically on a view when an activity is opened. No description or input from user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are plenty of libraries which you can use to show actions and their description on your views. We call it as Showcase of the views.

I am listing some of the libraries that you can use to fulfill your requirements.

- https://github.com/TakuSemba/Spotlight
- https://github.com/mreram/ShowCaseView
- https://github.com/deano2390/MaterialShowcaseView
- https://github.com/faruktoptas/FancyShowCaseView
- https://github.com/florent37/TutoShowcase

Comment: ended up using FancyShowCaseView, as it was the simplest for me with multiple shapes and a Show Once feature. Thanks!